# How can I get to the place where I can vote?

Tags: support, election

I would like to vote in the primary and election. At present I don't see any place where we can actually vote.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get to the voting page, click the link I've highlighted below:

[image: Highlight link]

Comment: It would have been nice to see the Droste effect in your picture. :)

Comment: +1 for [Red Freehand Circle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775)

Answer (score 3):

Each candidate has upvote/downvote arrows next to their post [on the primary page](https://math.stackexchange.com/election); that is how one votes in the primary. It is currently impossible to vote in the actual election because it has not started yet. Once the election starts, there will be 10 candidates, and you can choose up to three candidates to support, assigning them a ranking; thus, you might say

```
1st preference: Jill
```

or

```
1st preference: Bob
2nd preference: Jill
3rd preference: Alice
```

The mechanism for indicating these preferences will be specified on the election page once the election starts.